# How to receive data over Bluetooth serial port while in background

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an application that communicates over Bluetooth Serial Port with another terminal. It can send and receive data, more specifically text.

I can send and receive data successfully when the app is on foreground, however, I would like to know how I can make it so the app can receive data when in background and show it in the activity once it comes to foreground.

I'm currently using a service with the doInBackground(). However, I don't know what else I'm missing. Please assist me.

This is my service class

```
    package com.boson.BTComms;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BtService extends Service 
{   
    Bluetooth bt = new Bluetooth(); 
    static ConnectTask cTask;
    Bundle bndl;
    int action;

    public class rxBluetooth 
    {
        public String rxdMsg;
        public boolean newData;
        public boolean workerStatus;
        OutputStream mmOutputStream; // Stream de salida de la conexión
        InputStream mmInputStream;   // Stream de entrada de la conexión
        Thread workerThread; // Thread de escucha
        BluetoothSocket mmSocket; // Socket que se utiliza para comunicacion entre los dispositivos Bluetooth
        int readBufferPosition = 0; // Variable para bufer de lectura       
    }
    rxBluetooth rxBT = new rxBluetooth();   

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }   

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        bndl = intent.getExtras();
        action = bndl.getInt("act");        
        //MAIN SERVICE STATE-MACHINE
        switch (action)
        {
            case 0://Conexión
                try
                {                   
                    String remDev = bndl.getString("_remDev");
                    cTask = (ConnectTask) new ConnectTask().execute(remDev);                    
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not open connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);                   
                }
                break;

            case 1://Enviar Datos
                try
                {
                    if(rxBT.mmSocket != null && rxBT.mmSocket.isConnected() == true)
                    {                       
                        String msg = bndl.getString("_message");
                        rxBT.mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
                        rxBT.mmOutputStream.flush();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not send data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
                break;

            case 2://Cerrar Conexión
                rxBT.workerStatus = false;
                if (rxBT.mmInputStream != null) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        rxBT.mmInputStream.close();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {Log.e("BOSON", e.getMessage());}
                    rxBT.mmInputStream = null;
                }

                if (rxBT.mmOutputStream != null)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        rxBT.mmOutputStream.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {Log.e("BOSON", e.getMessage());}
                    rxBT.mmOutputStream = null;
                }

                if (rxBT.mmSocket != null) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        rxBT.mmSocket.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {Log.e("BOSON", e.getMessage());}
                    rxBT.mmSocket = null;
                }
                if (cTask != null)
                {
                    cTask.cancel(true);
                    cTask = null;
                }               
                break;
        }       
        return startId;
    }   

    private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try
            {               
                BluetoothDevice mmDevice = bt.btAdpt.getRemoteDevice(params[0]);
                try
                {
                    rxBT.mmSocket = mmDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mmDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                    rxBT.mmSocket.connect();         
                    rxBT.mmOutputStream = rxBT.mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                    rxBT.mmInputStream = rxBT.mmSocket.getInputStream();
                    Log.e("BOSON", rxBT.mmSocket.getRemoteDevice().toString());
                    Log.e("BOSON", rxBT.mmOutputStream.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("BOSON", "COULD NOT OPEN SOCKET CONNECTION");
                }

                rxBT.workerStatus = true;       
                Runnable rbleReceiver = new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {               
                        final byte delimiter = '\r';   
                        final byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesAvailable;
                        String rxdMsgT = "";
                        while(rxBT.workerStatus == true)
                        {
                            try                                         
                            {                    
                                if(rxBT.mmInputStream.available() > 0)
                                {         
                                    bytesAvailable = rxBT.mmInputStream.available();
                                    byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                    rxBT.mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);                                   
                                    for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++) 
                                    {
                                        byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                        if(b == delimiter) 
                                        {
                                            byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[rxBT.readBufferPosition];
                                            System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                            final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                            rxBT.readBufferPosition = 0;
                                            rxdMsgT = "Tu: " + data + "\n";
                                            rxBT.newData = true;
                                            if (rxBT.newData == true)
                                            {                
                                                Intent intent = new Intent("com.boson.BTComms.MainActivity");
                                                intent.putExtra("Mensaje", rxdMsgT);
                                                sendBroadcast(intent);                                                  
                                                rxBT.newData = false;
                                            }
                                        }                           
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            readBuffer[rxBT.readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Log.e("BOSON", "INACTIVE");
                                }
                            }
                            catch (IOException ex) 
                            {
                                rxBT.workerStatus = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                rxBT.workerThread = new Thread(rbleReceiver);
                rxBT.workerThread.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(BtService.this, "Could not open connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);                   
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Bluetooth on Android is confusing! What exactly isn't working? What does your code look like, and how is it behaving unexpectedly?

Comment: `doInBackground()` is an `AsyncTask` method, not a `Service` method. Using an actual `Service` should allow you to receive the data then store it wherever you'd like and check for updated data when the Activity comes to the foreground.

Comment: I'm actually using a service, but inside the service is an asynctask which is the process that I want to keep running in the background.